# How to grant access to a private load-balancer from an EBS environment using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an existing elasticbeanstalk environment, say `hello-env`. And I have created an `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`. I have made this service private. But I want to allow `hello-env` to access the load-balancer URL. How do I achieve that using CDK?

```
const cdk = require("aws-cdk-lib");
const { Construct } = require("constructs");
const ecs = require("aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs");
const ecsp = require("aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns");
const ecr = require("aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr");
const kms = require("aws-cdk-lib/aws-kms");
const ebs = require("aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticbeanstalk");

class MyEcsStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope, id, props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const myPvtService = new ecsp.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
      this,
      "MyPvtService",
      {
        cpu: 256,
        memoryLimitMiB: 512,
        desiredCount: 1,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(
            ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryAttributes(this, "MyPvtApp", {
              repositoryArn:
                "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:<my-account>:repository/my-pvt-app",
              repositoryName: "my-pvt-app",
            }),
            "dev"
          ),
          containerPort: 9000,
        },
        publicLoadBalancer: false,
      }
    );

    const myKey = kms.Key.fromKeyArn(
      this,
      "myKey",
      "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:<my-account>:key/mrk-28490388455e548c1998f64c89f853f61"
    );

    myKey.grant(
      myPvtService.taskDefinition.taskRole,
      "kms:GetPublicKey"
    );
    myKey.grant(myPvtService.taskDefinition.taskRole, "kms:Sign");

  }
}

module.exports = { MyEcsStack };
```

In the above code, I am allowing myPvtService to access the KMS keys. Similarly I want to allow an EBS Environment to access the load balancer service. How do I achieve that? There is no way to create and EBS env object using something like `fromArn`.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code of what you have and what you've tried so far?

Comment: @maafk I have added the code snippet where I want to add instantiate ebs and grant access to elb.